# How to remotely list a directory in the configured user's home directory

Tags: ssh

I notice that when doing one-liners via `ssh` into a Linux server, the value of `~` remains the value of the **local** user's home directory, not the remote user's home directory. Witness local user `dotancohen` and remote user `atwood`:

```
$ whoami
dotancohen

$ ssh beta whoami
atwood

$ ssh beta ls ~/.ssh
ls: cannot access /home/dotancohen/.ssh: No such file or directory

$ ssh beta ls $HOME/.ssh
ls: cannot access /home/dotancohen/.ssh: No such file or directory

$ ssh atwood@beta ls ~/.ssh
ls: cannot access /home/dotancohen/.ssh: No such file or directory

$ ssh beta ls /home/atwood/.ssh
authorized_keys

$ ssh beta ls .ssh             
authorized_keys
```

Note that even specifying the username in the connection details, and even using `$HOME` in place of `~` did not help. Not that I expected them to, but it was worth trying.

I have no problem looking in `.ssh/config` for the username when I'm doing one-liners if need be, but the inability to use `~` in scripts is rather inconvenient. **Other than parsing `~/.ssh/config` for the username, is there any way around this limitation?** The last example shows that I can *assume* that we're in his home directory and reference things relative to that, but I would prefer to explicitly call the directory if possible.

**How can I reference the user's home directory via SSH oneliners, without parsing `~/.ssh/config` locally for it?**

Tested on local system Kubuntu 14.04 and remote systems Ubuntu Server 12.04, 14.04, and RHEL 6.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to escape it so that your local shell doesn't expand it:

```
 ssh beta ls \~/.ssh
```

or

```
ssh beta 'ls ~/.ssh'
```

That should work.